# React typerror, is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error **TypeError: handleToggleSidebar is not a function** in **Dashboard.js**

Inside src/components/SideBar.js

```
export const SideBar = ({collapsed}) => { 
    return(
         <ProSidebar collapsed={collapsed}>
         ... rest of the code
    )
};
```

Inside src/pages/Dashboard.js

```
export const SideBar = ({handleCollapsedChange}) => { 
    return(
         <GiHamburgerMenu className="Hamburger_icon" onClick={() => handleCollapsedChange(true)} />
         ... rest of the code
    )
};
```

Inside src/App.js

```
 function App() {
 const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
 const handleCollapsedChange = (checked) => {
     setCollapsed(checked);
 };
 return (
     <div className="App">
     <Router>
     <SideBar
      collapsed={collapsed}
      handleCollapsedChange={handleCollapsedChange}
     />
     ... rest of the code
 )
};
```

Comment: Hi. Can you provide codesandbox?

Comment: @noob_nerd - here is the sandbox click onclick the mentioned error shows - https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-smoke-do6gu?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a different prop to be expected than what was passed down from your App.js.

```
export const SideBar = ({handleCollapsedChange}) => { 
    return(
         <GiHamburgerMenu className="Hamburger_icon" onClick={() => handleCollapsedChange(true)} />
         ... rest of the code
    )
};
```

Change your App.js to this, I changed your useState(), it should work now.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SideBar } from "./components/SideBar/SideBar";
import { Dashboard } from "./pages/Dashboard";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const handleCollapsedChange = () => {
    setCollapsed(!collapsed);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <SideBar
          collapsed={collapsed}
          handleCollapsedChange={handleCollapsedChange}
        />
        <Container>
          <Switch>
            {/* <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Dashboard handleCollapsedChange={handleCollapsedChange} />} /> */}
            <Route 
              path='/'
              render={(props) => (
                <Dashboard {...props} handleCollapsedChange={handleCollapsedChange} />
              )}
/>
            <Redirect to="/404" />
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I showed two implementations of the `<Route />` component but use the latter one (You can delete the commented one).

References:

https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-components/

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, but after changing i am getting the same error **TypeError: handleCollapsedChange is not a function**

Comment: I'm looking at your codesandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-smoke-do6gu?file=/src/pages/Dashboard.js:184-205

You never provided any props to Dashboard component you're routing to.

You can fix this error by providing a local state to the Dashboard component. Refactor the so code so that instead of passing down the state from App.js, Dashboard.js has its own local state. 

If your goal is for SideBar and Dashboard to share the same state, then just need to pass down the props to Dashboard as well.

Comment: <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Dashboard handleCollapsedChange={handleCollapsedChange} />} />

Comment: Your handleCollapsedChange was not defined properly. I updated the solution.